# How can I define a custom ant datatype that checks for required attributes?

Tags: ant

Ideally, I would like to throw an exception or log an error at the point where the data type is instantiated, rather than at some later time when the data type instance is referenced.

Is there a method that gets invoked at the point where the data type instance has been fully configured with attributes (and child elements)?